# Why am I not able to change form location in method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a load event and in that I am changing location. 
This code works fine:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.Location = new Point(1200,500); // as example
}
```

But if I give the location change to a method and call this method from load event, it does not work.

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ChangeLocation();
}

private void ChangeLocation()
{
    this.Location = new Point(1200,500); // as example
}
```

I am wondering why it can't be in method.
Thank you

Comment: What "does not work"?  Does it throw an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: That should be absolutely fine. Please define "does not work". Note that `MainForm_Load` is a method too, so it clearly *can* be in a method...

Comment: well, it doesnt't write any error. Everything is called properly, but location is not changed.

Comment: Are you sure its entering the method `ChangeLocation()`? What does not work then?

Comment: Yea, breakpoints are called if I give them to method.

Comment: Are there any other codes in `ChangeLocation`?

Comment: Your code, as is, works fine for me in a test application. If you create a new winforms project and do nothing but the above, does it not work? Or is it just failing in your real application?

Comment: is there any other code after you have called `ChangeLocation()` or something

Comment: Well, the fact that it works on yours computers forced me to try restart visual studio. It helped. I don't understand ... but it works.

Comment: i guess you needed to `Clean` and `Re-Build` your project :)

Comment: Next time I will try it like first ... thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

Set This

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

You will be able to set it manually

Comment: Tried. Nothing changed.